# How can I get the X-Auth-Token?

Tags: fiware-orion

I am trying to get a token from Orion Context Borker follow the wiki in this URL:

https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers

When i write my user and password, the script after five minutes only writes: "token:"

I run the script with this command: ./token_script.sh

Ask my user and password, and then the script writes:

token:

The token doesnt appear.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the *exact* command you use to run the script and the *exact* output you get (including the `token:` fragment), please?

Comment: The questions seems to be very similar to the one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674763/getting-token-in-orion-context-broker. I'd suggest to have it a look.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the port 4730, that port must be open to get the token.