# Getting Token in Orion Context Broker

Tags: authentication, token, fiware-orion, fiware

I'm trying to get an Authentication Token in order to start querying some information.
The problem is that when I execute the Token Script in Linux and I type my name and password, the server doesn't give me the token. I just get an empty space.
Does anybody know how to proceed?

**EDIT**: I just type

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client/master/token_script.sh
bash token_script.sh
```

In the Command Window in Ubuntu. The script asks me a user name and a password. When I write them, I just receive an empty space.

Thank you very much

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the exact command you use to run the script and the exact output you get, please?

Comment: Additional question (please, edit the question to include that information): is the result the same no matter if you instroduce a valid user/password or a invalid one (pe. foot@bar.com / foofoo)?

Comment: At the end I could get the Token. It was just one of the packages that caused me trouble (contextBroker-test). Is it necessary to run Orion through # contextBroker ? I could've asked some info about a sensor without it. When I do, I get an error (file not found) and I don't know why. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm happy to know that you solved the poblem at the end! However, it is a bit weird that contextBroker-test package was causing problems, as to get the token you are using two commands (wget and bash) that have nothing to do with contextBroker-test. Reading last part in your comment (the part on "I don't know why"), I'm not sure if you have any additional problem (after solved the problem with the token). In that case, don't hesitate to ask again (in another post at StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@fi-next /]# wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client/master/token_script.sh
--2017-08-01 09:59:27--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client/master/token_script.sh
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 151.101.0.133, 151.101.64.133, 151.101.128.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.0.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 288 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘token_script.sh’

100%[====================================>] 288    --.-K/s   in 0s

2017-08-01 09:59:27 (25.1 MB/s) - ‘token_script.sh’ saved [288/288]

[root@fi-next /]# bash token_script.sh

Username: fernando.mendez.external@atos.net
Password:

Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Hi, it's worked for me.

You must have an account in fiware lab

Regards